# Cisco 1841 won't initiate site2site VPN

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa, ipsec

I'm trying to establish the site2site VPN using Cisco 1841 with dynamic WAN IP on one side (LAN 192.168.101.0/24) and Cisco ASA 5505 with static WAN IP on the other side (LAN 192.168.100.0/24).

Cisco 1841 won't establish the tunnel:

```
c1841#debug crypto engine
Crypto Engine debugging is on
c1841#debug crypto isakmp
Crypto ISAKMP debugging is on
c1841#debug crypto IPSec
Crypto IPSEC debugging is on
c1841#ping 192.168.100.1

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.100.1, timeout is 2 seconds:

*Oct  3 19:40:18.239: IPSEC(sa_initiate): Kicking the dialer interface.
*Oct  3 19:40:20.239: IPSEC(sa_initiate): Kicking the dialer interface
*Oct  3 19:40:20.419: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Cellular0/0/0, changed state to up
*Oct  3 19:40:21.199: IPSEC(recalculate_mtu): reset sadb_root 64F85A74 mtu to 1500.
*Oct  3 19:40:21.419: %LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface Cellular0/0/0, changed state to up...
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
```

And that's all. ASA 5505 doesn't have anything in debug.

How do I fix/diagnose this? Please help.

Comment: That ping probably has the router's WAN address as source and therefor does not bring up the tunnel because it doesn't match the crypto map. Try `ping 192.168.100.1 source 192.168.101.x` where the latter is your router's LAN address. If that doesn't help please post your router config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that NAT rule on 1841 processed the packet before ACL. Thanks everyone for the hints.

Answer (score 0):

Presumable you have a single line in your crypto ACL, matching traffic between 192.168.100.0/24 and 192.168.101.0/24.

Therefor, when you simply do `ping 192.168.100.1` this will generate ICMP packets with the router's WAN address as the source IP address, and hence these ICMP packets do not match the crypto ACL so it is normal that this does not bring up the tunnel.

So in order to bring up the tunnel you need to either ping from the LAN (i.e. from a device with an 192.168.101.x address) or from the router do an extended ping like

```
ping 192.168.100.1 source 192.168.101.1
```

where `192.168.101.1` is the ip address of the router's LAN interface, or

```
ping 192.168.100.1 source FastEthernet0/1
```

where `FastEthernet0/1` is your LAN interface.

Note that you can also [configure IP SLA](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipsla/configuration/15-mt/sla-15-mt-book/sla_icmp_echo.html) to keep the tunnel up, and in that config you will also have to add a `source-ip`  or `source-interface` argument.